# What if one remains in limit in the relationship during these days?

Tags: halal-haram, relationships

I have relationship with a girl for about two years. We just text each other. And we promised each other not to come close to each other until we marry And by the grace of Allah we're fullfilling it and we will insha'Allah . And as far as I know these type of relationships are not permissible if one thinks he may fall to the worst sin (zina). Is it permissible because it protects both of us from many sins (e.g masturbation,pornography etc)?

Comment: These kinds of relationships are not permissible no matter what.

Comment: Is there any way to be authentic (in the light of Quran and Sunnah) like we promised each other. Means we left the pathway that leads to zina.

Comment: @Hassan Yes, it's called marriage!

Comment: @Crimson I think you're not getting my point. I want to ask if it's halal or haram because we have promised each other not to meet physically untill nikkah.

Comment: My comment was an answer to the question in your comment above.

Answer (score 0):

You can start engagement, and of course there will be limits as you do now, until you both are ready for marriage.

Comment: We both are 18 year old and studying. Engagement isn't possible. I am just asking is texting allowed if we promised not to physically meet each other.

Comment: @Hassan why is engagement impossible?

Answer (score 0):

السلام عليكم ورحمة الله وبركاته

Sin does not protect you from another sin, but rather it causes you to fall into another sin, so stop and ask Allahﷻ for success in marriage